# Populating a JComboBox with field from SQLite database

Tags: java, database, sqlite, combobox, populate

I'm trying to get a combobox that populates from a SQLite database. The code I have is below ...

```
public void fillYearGroup() {
        try {
            String query="select * from YearGroups";
            PreparedStatement pst=connection.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next())
            {
                cmbYearGroup.addItem(rs.getString("YearGroup"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I've added the call statement here:

```
cmbYearGroup = new JComboBox();
cmbYearGroup.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
cmbYearGroup.setBounds(171, 44, 57, 27);
contentPane.add(cmbYearGroup);
fillYearGroup();
```

Although I'm getting no errors the combobox appears empty in the preview. Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong here? The console is saying the following:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Administrator.fillYearGroup(Administrator.java:71)
    at Administrator.<init>(Administrator.java:279)
    at Administrator$1.run(Administrator.java:55)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The full code

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;

import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class Administrator extends JFrame {
    Connection connection=null; 
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField txtAForename;
    private JTextField txtASurname;
    private JTextField txtAYearGroup;
    private JTextField txtAAssessment;
    private JTextField txtAPracticalSet;
    private JTextField txtARegSet;
    private JTextField txtALastUpdated;
    private JTextField txtAMedical;
    private JTextField txtABehaviour;
    private JTextField txtABarriers;
    private JTextField txtAStrategies;
    private JTextField txtALastUpdate;
    private JTextField txtSForename;
    private JTextField txtSSurname;
    private JTable table;
    private JComboBox cmbYearGroup;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Administrator frame = new Administrator();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */

    public void fillYearGroup() {
        try {
            String query="select * from YearGroups";
            System.out.println(connection);
            PreparedStatement pst=connection.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next())
            {
                cmbYearGroup.addItem(rs.getString("YearGroup"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void refreshTable() {

        try {
            String query="select Forename, Surname, Behaviour, Medical, Barriers, Strategies, Assessment from S1Pupils";
            PreparedStatement pst=connection.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
            table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public Administrator() {
        Connection connection = sqliteConnection.dbConnector();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 850, 676);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        txtAForename = new JTextField();
        txtAForename.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        txtAForename.setColumns(10);
        txtAForename.setBounds(10, 299, 129, 27);
        contentPane.add(txtAForename);

        txtASurname = new JTextField();
        txtASurname.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        txtASurname.setColumns(10);
        txtASurname.setBounds(149, 299, 129, 27);
        contentPane.add(txtASurname);

        txtAYearGroup = new JTextField();
        txtAYearGroup.setColumns(10);
        txtAYearGroup.setBounds(288, 300, 74, 27);
        contentPane.add(txtAYearGroup);

        txtAAssessment = new JTextField();
        txtAAssessment.setColumns(10);
        txtAAssessment.setBounds(372, 300, 74, 27);
        contentPane.add(txtAAssessment);

        JLabel lblAssessment = new JLabel("Assesment");
        lblAssessment.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        lblAssessment.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        lblAssessment.setBounds(372, 280, 86, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblAssessment);

        JLabel lblYearGroup = new JLabel("Year Group");
        lblYearGroup.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        lblYearGroup.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        lblYearGroup.setBounds(288, 280, 74, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblYearGroup);

        JLabel lblForename = new JLabel("Forename");
        lblForename.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        lblForename.setBounds(10, 279, 74, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblForename);

        JLabel lblSurname = new JLabel("Surname");
        lblSurname.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        lblSurname.setBounds(149, 279, 74, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblSurname);

        JCheckBox chcALaac = new JCheckBox("LAAC");
        chcALaac.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        chcALaac.setBounds(720, 272, 86, 23);
        contentPane.add(chcALaac);

        JCheckBox chcAArmyChild = new JCheckBox("Army child");
        chcAArmyChild.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        chcAArmyChild.setBounds(720, 298, 90, 23);
        contentPane.add(chcAArmyChild);

        JCheckBox chcAYoungCarer = new JCheckBox("Y - carer");
        chcAYoungCarer.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        chcAYoungCarer.setBounds(720, 324, 86, 23);
        contentPane.add(chcAYoungCarer);

        txtAPracticalSet = new JTextField();
        txtAPracticalSet.setColumns(10);
        txtAPracticalSet.setBounds(452, 299, 80, 27);
        contentPane.add(txtAPracticalSet);

        txtARegSet = new JTextField();
        txtARegSet.setColumns(10);
        txtARegSet.setBounds(542, 299, 80, 27);
        contentPane.add(txtARegSet);

        txtALastUpdated = new JTextField();
        txtALastUpdated.setColumns(10);
        txtALastUpdated.setBounds(632, 300, 86, 27);
        contentPane.add(txtALastUpdated);

        JLabel lblPracticalSet = new JLabel("Practical Set");
        lblPracticalSet.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        lblPracticalSet.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        lblPracticalSet.setBounds(454, 279, 90, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblPracticalSet);

        JLabel lblRegSet = new JLabel("Reg Set");
        lblRegSet.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        lblRegSet.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        lblRegSet.setBounds(542, 279, 80, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblRegSet);

        JLabel lblLastUpdated = new JLabel("Last Updated");
        lblLastUpdated.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        lblLastUpdated.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        lblLastUpdated.setBounds(628, 278, 84, 17);
        contentPane.add(lblLastUpdated);

        txtAMedical = new JTextField();
        txtAMedical.setColumns(10);
        txtAMedical.setBounds(137, 355, 687, 27);
        contentPane.add(txtAMedical);

        txtABehaviour = new JTextField();
        txtABehaviour.setColumns(10);
        txtABehaviour.setBounds(137, 393, 687, 27);
        contentPane.add(txtABehaviour);

        txtABarriers = new JTextField();
        txtABarriers.setColumns(10);
        txtABarriers.setBounds(137, 431, 687, 44);
        contentPane.add(txtABarriers);

        txtAStrategies = new JTextField();
        txtAStrategies.setColumns(10);
        txtAStrategies.setBounds(137, 489, 687, 44);
        contentPane.add(txtAStrategies);

        txtALastUpdate = new JTextField();
        txtALastUpdate.setColumns(10);
        txtALastUpdate.setBounds(137, 548, 687, 44);
        contentPane.add(txtALastUpdate);

        JLabel lblMedical = new JLabel("Medical");
        lblMedical.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
        lblMedical.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        lblMedical.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        lblMedical.setBounds(31, 361, 98, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblMedical);

        JLabel lblBehaviour = new JLabel("Behaviour");
        lblBehaviour.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        lblBehaviour.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        lblBehaviour.setBounds(29, 398, 100, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblBehaviour);

        JLabel lblBarriers = new JLabel("Barriers to learning");
        lblBarriers.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        lblBarriers.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        lblBarriers.setBounds(10, 441, 119, 23);
        contentPane.add(lblBarriers);

        JLabel lblStrategies = new JLabel("Strategies");
        lblStrategies.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        lblStrategies.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        lblStrategies.setBounds(31, 499, 100, 23);
        contentPane.add(lblStrategies);

        JLabel lblLastUpdate = new JLabel("Last update");
        lblLastUpdate.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        lblLastUpdate.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        lblLastUpdate.setBounds(31, 558, 98, 23);
        contentPane.add(lblLastUpdate);

        JButton btnSave = new JButton("Save record");
        btnSave.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        btnSave.setBounds(705, 603, 119, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnSave);

        txtSForename = new JTextField();
        txtSForename.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        txtSForename.setColumns(10);
        txtSForename.setBounds(10, 44, 129, 27);
        contentPane.add(txtSForename);

        txtSSurname = new JTextField();
        txtSSurname.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        txtSSurname.setColumns(10);
        txtSSurname.setBounds(10, 98, 129, 27);
        contentPane.add(txtSSurname);

        JLabel lblSearchByName = new JLabel("Filter by...");
        lblSearchByName.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        lblSearchByName.setBounds(10, 1, 150, 23);
        contentPane.add(lblSearchByName);

        JComboBox cmbYearGroup = new JComboBox();
        cmbYearGroup.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        cmbYearGroup.setBounds(171, 44, 57, 27);
        contentPane.add(cmbYearGroup);
        fillYearGroup();
        revalidate();
        repaint();

        JLabel lblFForename = new JLabel("Forename");
        lblFForename.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        lblFForename.setBounds(10, 26, 74, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblFForename);

        JLabel lblFSurname = new JLabel("Surname");
        lblFSurname.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        lblFSurname.setBounds(10, 77, 74, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblFSurname);

        JLabel lblFRegSet = new JLabel("Registration Set");
        lblFRegSet.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        lblFRegSet.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        lblFRegSet.setBounds(305, 24, 107, 19);
        contentPane.add(lblFRegSet);

        JComboBox cmbRegSet = new JComboBox();
        cmbRegSet.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        cmbRegSet.setBounds(305, 42, 67, 27);
        contentPane.add(cmbRegSet);


        JLabel lblFYearGroup = new JLabel("Year Group");
        lblFYearGroup.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        lblFYearGroup.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        lblFYearGroup.setBounds(172, 26, 74, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblFYearGroup);



        JComboBox cmbPracticalSet = new JComboBox();
        cmbPracticalSet.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        cmbPracticalSet.setBounds(305, 98, 67, 27);
        contentPane.add(cmbPracticalSet);

        JLabel lblFPracticalSet = new JLabel("Practical Set");
        lblFPracticalSet.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        lblFPracticalSet.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        lblFPracticalSet.setBounds(305, 82, 86, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblFPracticalSet);

        JComboBox cmbSubject = new JComboBox();
        cmbSubject.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        cmbSubject.setBounds(485, 44, 211, 27);
        contentPane.add(cmbSubject);

        JLabel lblFSubject = new JLabel("Subject");
        lblFSubject.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        lblFSubject.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        lblFSubject.setBounds(485, 26, 129, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblFSubject);

        JLabel lblFColumn = new JLabel("Column");
        lblFColumn.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        lblFColumn.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        lblFColumn.setBounds(485, 82, 57, 15);
        contentPane.add(lblFColumn);

        JComboBox cmbColumn = new JComboBox();
        cmbColumn.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        cmbColumn.setBounds(485, 98, 67, 27);
        contentPane.add(cmbColumn);

        JLabel lblFColumnSet = new JLabel(" Column set");
        lblFColumnSet.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        lblFColumnSet.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        lblFColumnSet.setBounds(562, 81, 90, 16);
        contentPane.add(lblFColumnSet);

        JComboBox cmbColumnSet = new JComboBox();
        cmbColumnSet.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        cmbColumnSet.setBounds(562, 98, 67, 27);
        contentPane.add(cmbColumnSet);

        JButton btnFilter = new JButton("Filter");
        btnFilter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent arg0) {

                try {
                    String query="select Forename, Surname, YearGroup, Behaviour, Medical, Barriers, Strategies, Assessment from S1Pupils";
                    PreparedStatement pst=connection.prepareStatement(query);
                    ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
                    table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                } catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

                });
        btnFilter.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        btnFilter.setBounds(720, 101, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnFilter);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(10, 136, 814, 134);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane);

        table = new JTable();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Could be your UI is not updated after the call to `fillYearGroup()`. Try adding: `revalidate(); repaint();`

Comment: I've tried adding both of these but it doesn't seem to have helped. The console is spitting the following out at me though which I've only just noticed (edited the original post).

Comment: which line in your code is 71?

Comment: 71: PreparedStatement pst=connection.prepareStatement(query); (part of the above function)

Comment: Perhaps you should add `System.out.println(connection);` before that line, to verify that your Connection is not null.

Comment: I've added that in VGR but the combobox still isn't filling, I'll edit the original post to include all of the code.

Comment: And what did that line print?  Line 71 (now line 72) should not be able to generate a NullPointerException unless the Connection is null.

Comment: It seems your line `Connection connection = sqliteConnection.dbConnector();`is initialising connection to `null`. I am not actually sure what it is supposed to do, is `sqliteConnection` a member of your class?